# MVC actionlink class after refresh of partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dialog

I have a view with a partial view in it. The partial view contains the attachments of a file (in a ipagedlist). The last column of the ipagedlist contains a actionlink for deleting the attachment. After clicking the delete-actionlink a jquery confirmation dialog appears (using a class for the actionlink). When the user confirms the deletion of the record it removes from the database. For so far it works great. After removing the record the list of attachments is refreshed (by refreshing the partial-view). 
Then when the view is refreshed and the user wants to delete another record by pressing the delete-link of another record the record is instantly deleted. No confirmation dialog is shown.

It seems to me that after the reload the class is not used anymore for the delete-links. But i cant figure out how to make the actionlinks in the reloaded modal window also use the class.

My code for the actionlink (in the partialview) is:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Verwijderen", "_DeleteAttachment", "Attachment", new { attachmentId = @item.Id }, new { @class = "delete-link" })
```

The code for the confirmation dialog:

```
<script>
    var deleteLinkObj;

    // delete Link
    $('.delete-link').click(function () {
        deleteLinkObj = $(this);  //for future use
        $('#delete-dialog').dialog('open');
        return false; // prevents the default behaviour
    });
</script>

<script>
    $('#delete-dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false, width: 400, resizable: false, modal: true, //Dialog options
        buttons: {
            "Continue": function () {
                $.post(deleteLinkObj[0].href, function (data) {  //Post to action
                    if (data == 'True') {
                        $("#eCommerceFileAttachmentsDiv").load('@Url.Action("_ExistingAttachments", "Attachment", new { eCommerceFileId = @Model.Id, readOnly = ViewBag.disableControls })'); //Hide Row
                        $('#delete-dialog').dialog('close');
                        //(optional) Display Confirmation
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Refresh mislukt!");
                        $("#eCommerceFileAttachmentsDiv").load('@Url.Action("_ExistingAttachments", "Attachment", new { eCommerceFileId = @Model.Id, readOnly = ViewBag.disableControls })'); //Hide Row
                        //(optional) Display Error
                    }
                });
                //$(this).dialog("close");
                $('#delete-dialog').dialog('close');
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $('#delete-dialog').dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

I hope somebody can help me solving this issue.

Comment: You need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for events in dynamically added elements

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '.delete-link', click(function () {` (but replace `document with the closest ancestor which exists when the page is first rendered)

Comment: But why not just delete the associated elements (row?) from the DOM rather than reloading the whole partial?

Comment: @StephenMuecke offcourse, that solved the problem. I was thinking to difficult. Thanks for your help!